# Retrieve JSON object from Google Sheets using Sheetrock.js

Tags: javascript, json, google-sheets, sheetrock

I am using [Sheetrock.js](https://github.com/chriszarate/sheetrock) to allow me to query a public google spreadsheet. It currently works and is populating a HTML table with the data it is returning. I am using it like so:

```
$('#spreadsheet').sheetrock({
    url: mySpreadsheet,
    query: "select B,Y,AD order by AB asc",
    labels: ['Name', 'Levels Skipped', 'Time'],
    fetchSize: 10
});
```

Instead of using the data to populate a table I now want to get the data as some JSON so I can use it in my JavaScript code but do not know how to do so.